# C++ String comparison not working as intended

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, compare

I am trying to compare two strings for a trivia program, one entered by a user and the other accessed from a node. The comparison is within an IF statement and always returns false. Below is the code used for this function. Both variables userAnswer and answer are of the type string.

```
cout << "Question: " << cur_ptr->question << endl;
cout << "Answer: ";
getline(cin, userAnswer);
if (userAnswer == cur_ptr->answer) {
    cout << "Your answer is correct. You receive " << cur_ptr->points << " points." << endl;
    totalPoints += cur_ptr->points;
}
else {
    cout << "Your answer is wrong. The correct answer is: " << cur_ptr->answer << endl;
}
cout << "Your total points: " << totalPoints << endl << endl;
cur_ptr = cur_ptr->next;
```

Whenever my program runs, it generates an output like so

```
Question: How long was the shortest war on Record? (Hint: how many minutes)?
Answer: 38
Your answer is wrong. The correct answer is: 38
Your total points: 0
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. Maybe the strings contain some whitespace or strange characters? http://ideone.com/xnYHYg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getline(cin, userAnswer)` is keeping the `\n`. You might consider trimming the string with something like the following

```
getline(cin, userAnswer);
userAnswer.erase(userAnswer.find_last_not_of("\n\r") + 1);
```

No guarantees that this is the answer, but I've run across this a few times and it's just been a trailing `\n` or `\r`.

Comment: Thank you!! This did work for my code. Quick question though. What is the purpose of the +1 in that line of code.

Comment: @Neal You should find out where the extra whitespace gets inserted into the string and prevent that.

Comment: `find_last_not_of` does like exactly what it sounds like it does. So the last character that was not a `\n` or `\r` was a character you needed. E.g. `std::string s("Hello, World!"); s.erase(s.find_last_not_of("!"));` would give you "Hello, Worl". In this case `erase` takes a `size_t` that equates to the number of characters you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Do some `boost::trim()` on the strings to compare, before the comparison, and see if that helps.